# Efficient way for variance of a continuous variable A at a point i? Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a continuous variable `A=gamrnd(5,0.4,1000,28)` and an output variable `Y=lognrnd(7,1.9,1000,28)`

```
 A
    7.6472    3.4284    6.3352    8.0480    8.1021
   12.3371    5.1611    6.3986    9.3687    9.5652
    8.7700    5.2980    6.0307    2.8651   12.6011
   12.2042    4.5636    6.0570    7.1348    8.6586
    7.8960    5.5213    3.7105    6.4875    7.4891

 Y
    1.9733   14.0951   14.0951   14.0951   14.0951
    9.4284   11.7573   15.6730   25.4495   24.6680
    3.4724    4.4953    7.1237    9.4191   18.4504
    8.9548    8.9548    8.9548    8.9548    8.9548
    1.4834    2.5393    2.5393    2.5393    2.5393
```

I'd like to calculate the `variance` of `Y` for a specific value of A (or width) of that red box? let's say I split the domain of `A` into 20 red boxes, I would like to calculate the variance of `Y` for each box.  That is to say:

$Var(Y|A=a_i)$

Any thought how I'd do that?

My thoughts so far:

```
[i j]=find(9.5<=A & A<=10.5)
sig=var(reshape((Y([i j])),length(i)*2,1))
```

but this is correct but rather ad-hoc. Let's say I had a hundred divisions in A. Is it possible to use something more efficient?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accumarray` to the rescue!

```
%# split A into 100 chunks
nChunks = 100;

Aidx = round(A/maxA*(nChunks-1))+1;

%# get the number of data points just in case
nDataPoints = histc(Aidx,1:nChunks);

%# calculate the variance
varA = accumarray(Aidx,Y,[100,1],@var,NaN);
```

Comment: I'm getting `Error using accumarray
Second input VAL must be a vector with one element for each row in
SUBS, or a scalar.` Y is 1000x28

Comment: @user1134241: either you should linearize A and Y first (A=A(:)) in case the variance should be over all the values in Y together, or you run the code for each column of A and Y, respectively, in case you want the variance for each pair of columns in A and Y.

Comment: Good call, realised they don't need to be ordered.